# Use DFT twice for MFCC extraction engine or use both DFT and DCT?

Tags: fft, dft, mfcc, dct

I'm in the process of designing an MFC extraction engine on an FPGA using Verilog.
My primary concern is whether I can implement the DFT twice in the MFCC calculation process: once before applying the Mel filters and then again after. Alternatively, would it be more appropriate to use a combination of the DFT and DCT?

My aim is to minimize the need for additional hardware modules, and I'm wondering if I can efficiently reuse the DFT IP core for both steps.

If it's possible to use the DFT twice, how does this dual implementation work in the context of MFCC calculation? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on optimizing the FPGA design for this purpose.

PS : I am still a fresher.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.